# What is the difference between join() and enter() in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been getting into data visualization with d3.js, but there is one thing that I have not been able to wrap my head around. What is the difference between `d3.join()` and `d3.enter()`? Is `enter()` to be used mainly for dynamic data? Or is `join()` an overarching method that contains `enter()`, `exit()`, and `update()`?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69819222/7106086) useful (while the question itself references .append(), in this question's context, .append() usually follows .enter())?

Comment: @AndrewReid that pretty much answers it! Thank you!

Comment: Just as an additional information, there's no `d3.join` or `d3.enter` in D3. It's `selection.join` etc.